# Property 'args' does not exist on type (args: Props)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I can't understand why I'm receiving this error `Property 'args' does not exist on type (args: Props) => Element`

I'm trying to add args to my Storybook component. This is how my `.stories.tsx` file looks like

```
import React from "react";
import { Story, Meta } from "@storybook/react";

import { Props, Button } from ".";

export default {
  title: "General/Button",
  component: Button
} as Meta;

const Template = (args: Props) => <Button {...args} />;

export const PrimaryA = Template.bind({});

PrimaryA.args = {  <-- ERROR
  variant: "primary"
};
```

And simple `.tsx` file of Button component

```
import { css } from "@emotion/react";
import React from "react";

export interface Props {
   args: {
     variant: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
  },
}

const style = css`
  .primary {
    background: #0082ff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
`;

export function Button(props: Props) {
  const { variant = "primary", children = "Primary", ...rest } = props.args;
  return (
    <div css={style} className={`button ${variant}`} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

How you can see I have there is already `.args` property in the interface Props. I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks :))

Edit.

I edited interface

```
export interface Props {
  variant: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

As well as `PrimaryA` object

```
const Template = (props: Props) => <Button {...props} />;

export const PrimaryA = Template({
  variant: "disabled"
});
```

And still nothing. I can't see component at the Storybook

Comment: Args is an argument of the arrow function 'Template' but not a property of Element, so the error is correct

Comment: Use PrimaryA = Template(args); instead

Comment: But `Button` as element also receives args `Button(props: Props)`

Comment: Button receive args as an attribute of its props (as defined in the Props interface). It does not mean args is an attribute of Button

Comment: It still don't works

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to use the Typescript version, it's an option in the docs now (https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/whats-a-story), but the relevant code is below:

```
import {Meta, Story} from "@storybook/react";

export default {
  title: "Button",
  component: Button,
} as Meta;

// We create a “template” of how args map to rendering
const Template: Story<ButtonProps> = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

export const Primary = Template.bind({});

Primary.args = {
  primary: true,
  label: 'Primary',
};
```

Comment: `Story` appears to be deprecated in Storybook 7, `StoryFn` appears to work.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using vue3

```js
import Button from '../components/Button.vue'
import { IButtonProps } from '../types/types'
import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/vue3'

export default {
  title: 'Example/Button',
  component: Button,
  argTypes:{
    backgroundColor: { control: 'color' },
    size: {
      control: { type: 'select', options: ['small', 'medium', 'large'] },
    },
    onClick: {},
  },
} as Meta;


    const Template: Story<IButtonProps>  = (args ) => ({
  components: { Button },
  setup() {
    return { args }
  },
  template: '<Button v-bind="args" />',
})

export const Primary = Template.bind({})
Primary.args = {
  primary: true,
  title: '\u{1F9D1}\u{200D}\u{1F3A8}',
  backgrounColor: 'red'
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.